# How to make topology smooth in Blender for rounded object (helmet modeling)

Tags: modeling, objects, vertices, sculpting, topology

I have managed to make a relatively spherical object using plane extrude technique. I use Blender 2.9. Just to be more specific, I use Schuberth RF1 helmet model as a refernce. So far, this is what I have come up with.

[image]

However, since modeled using this technique, I have struggled to smoothen the surface of the helmet I modeled to appear in a uniform flat surface of a sphere. You can see on the below pictures that the top part of the helmet is a bit uneven.

[image]
[image]

Do we have an option in blender to smoothen the top part so it looks really even?

Comment: You could try selecting all the vertices in the area in edit mode and then select Smooth Vertices from the Vertex menu. Also Shade Smooth from the right-click menu in Object Mode might help.

Comment: @JohnEason The Smooth Vertices worked really well. Thank you for your prompt reply!

Comment: Good! Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the comments from John Eason under my question and AsianMario's answers. In this case, the Smooth Vertices worked really well to polish the topology that I already have

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried shade smoothing the whole object? If you start having problems with the normals go to: Object Data Properties > Normals > Autosmooth.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to apply the suggestions on the comment from my question above and it worked really well for me. What I need is to make the topology smooth, not just the shading for the jagged edges. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Ah alright, can't really help you word-by word on that but here's a video that might help you. Good luck! [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YkUxB_bka3U)